# JNI 64 бит x64 на FASM или ASM

Tags: java, ассемблер, jni, fasm

Хочу написать взаимодействие jni и fasm на x64 битной архитектуре и возникла небольшая проблема.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_t_TeastJNI_sum
    (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);
```

Попытался решить проблему в лоб, возвращал параметры через eax или через rax, но dll возвращал только какое-то рандомное число:

```
Java_t_TestJNI_sum:
    mov rax, [rsp+24] ; пропускаем 2 параметра
    add rax, [rsp+32]
    ret 32
```

Может я неправильно понял параметры stdcall?

Можно реализацию не только на FASM, на любом ASM x86-64.

UPD0

Полностью dll выглядит так:

```
format PE64 condole dll
include '%fasminc%\win64a.inc'
entry DllStart

section '.text' code readable executable

proc DllStart hinstDll,fdwReason,lpvReserved
    mov eax,TRUE
    ret
endp

Java_t_TestJNI_sum:
    mov rax,[R8]
    add rax,[R9]
    ret

section '.edata' expirt data readable

export 'mydll.dlll',\
    Java_t_TestJNI_sum,'Java_t_TestJNI_sum'
```

Метод java всё тот же, но возникла ошибка:

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=******* и т.д.
Problematic frame:
C [mydll.dll+0x1000]
```

UPD1
Исправил как еаписали здесь, но:
    format PE64 console dll

```
include '%fasminc%\WIN64A.INC'

section '.text' code readable executable
  proc Java_t_TestJNI_sum
    mov rax, r8
    add rax, r9
    ret
  endp


section '.edata' export data readable
  export 'mydll.dll',\
    Java_t_TestJNI_sum, 'Java_t_TestJNI_sum'


section '.reloc' fixups data discardable
  if $=$$
    dd 0,8 
  end if
```

Ошибка UnsatisfiedLinkError: Попытка обращения к неверному адресу

Ошибка возникает всегда, но при удалении секции .reloc ошибка возникает рандомно, а иногда всё хорошо. Если в секции .reloc сделать так:

```
dd 0,64
```

Что выделяет больше места для секции, насколько я понимаю, то ошибка исчезает полностью.

Куда пропала ошибка, и не прячется ли она, чтобы снова рандомно вылезти когда не нужно? Не зависит ли теперь код от "фазы луны"? (Чего-то непонятного в x86-64, исключая: ошибки в самих процессорах этого семейства, баги windows, запуска кода в неподдерживающих код средах).

UPD2 вопрос закрыт, можно ещё просто в конце edata написать вместо reloc:

```
data fixups
end data
```

Comment: На 64 битах ведь нет stdcall, там одно соглашение (ABI) для Windows, и одно для юниксов. При небольшом количестве параметров стек для их передачи не используется. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions

Comment: MBo, ясно, но у меня не сработало, нужно как-то особо создавать функцию на ASM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде множество опечаток и бездумного копирования из разных источников.

```
format PE64 console dll

include '%fasminc%\WIN64A.INC'

section '.text' code readable executable
  proc Java_t_TestJNI_sum
    mov rax, r8
    add rax, r9
    ret
  endp


section '.edata' export data readable
  export 'mydll.dll',\
    Java_t_TestJNI_sum, 'Java_t_TestJNI_sum'


section '.reloc' fixups data discardable
  if $=$$
    dd 0, 64  ; if there are no fixups, generate dummy entry
  end if
```

Comment: dd 0,8 у меня не работает, только dd 0,64 прошу поправить ваш ответ, чтобы я мог его принять как верный

Comment: @Askalite исправил. Лучше посмотрите на yasm, в нём не нужны пляски с фиксапами.