# C в Java? Или ключевое слово native

Tags: java, jni, native

```
public native int hashCode()
```

Впервые увидел вот такое слово `native`.

Из википедии:

> Java Native Interface (JNI) — стандартный механизм для запуска кода, под управлением виртуальной машины Java (JVM), который написан на языках С/С++ или Ассемблера, и скомпонован в виде динамических библиотек, позволяет не использовать статическое связывание. Это даёт возможность вызова функции С/С++ из программы на Java, и наоборот.

Как это понять что `C` язык "находится" в `Java`?

Comment: не язык С, а скомпилированный нативный код

Comment: директива native и JNI никак не связаны

Comment: @pavlofff Запутался значит, расскажите пожалуйста о native, почему он в Java и что за скомпилированный нативный код, нативный для чего?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Запутался значит, расскажите пожалуйста о native, почему он в Java и что за скомпилированный нативный код, нативный для чего?

Comment: @MikeMclaren Вам ответили

Comment: Если по простому, вы пишите на любом компилируемом языке библиотеку (dll или so), функции которой выполняются при вызове native-методов. Простой и подробный [пример на C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678881/204271) установки системного времени нативным вызовом. Вот [пример на ассемблере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/894132/204271). А ещё JNI позволяет выполнить и обратную связь - [запустить виртуальную машину из бинарника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/886507/204271).

Comment: Вот [пример](http://java-course.ru/articles/jni/)

Answer (score 7):

Весьма старая инфа, однако, объясняет довольно понятно:

Если в процессе реализации Jаvа-проекта возникает необходимость в применении существующего кода, написанного на другом языке программирования, или использовании низкоуровневых функций для непосредственного обращения к компьютерной аппаратуре, существует возможность прибегнуть к так называемым методам `native`, которые могут быть вызваны из среды приложения Java, но создаются на одном из "родственных" `(native)` языков – как правило, С или С++. Nаtivе-методы объявляются посредством модификатора native. Тело метода реализуется на другом языке и поэтому в объявлении заменяется символом точки с запятой. Ниже в качестве примера приведено объявление метода, который обращается к операционной системе за информацией об идентификационном номере процессора хост-компьютера.

```
public native int getCPUID();
```

Единственное отличие методов native состоит в том, что они реализуются на другом языке программирования. В остальном они подобны обычным методам, т.е. могут быть переопределены, перегружены и снабжены любыми модификаторами – `final, static, synchronized, public, protected или private (кроме abstract и strictfp)`.

При обращении к методам native свойства переносимости и безопасности, присущие коду Java, будут утрачены. Практически невозможно использовать методы `native` в Jаvа-коде, который предназначен для загрузки из Internet или выполнения на удаленных компьютерах сети (примером являются аплеты). Не исключено, что работать с вашим кодом придется системе совершенно другой архитектуры, но если даже это и не так, система может просто запретить выполнение кода, не вызывающего доверия.

Методы `native` реализуются с помощью библиотек API, предлагаемых разработчиками виртуальных машин Java для тех или иных платформ. Одна из стандартных библиотек API, предназначенных для программистов, использующих язык С, носит название `JNI` – от `Java Native Iпterface`. Существуют библиотеки и для других языков.

Comment: `как правило, С или С++` это ключевое, что не обязательно Си =)