# Почему System.out объявлен как final, но не инициализирован?

Tags: java

Я изучаю Java, и у меня возник вопрос по методу System.**out**.println(),
а конкретнее, что именно означает слово **out** в нём.

Поковырявшись, я нашел это:

```
public final class System {

    public static final InputStream in;

    public static final PrintStream out;
```

Там это работает. Но когда я пытаюсь создать свой класс с полем

```
public static final PrintStream out;
```

например

```
public final class MoyKlass{
    public static final PrintStream out;
```

выдаёт ошибку: значение `out` должно быть инициализировано

Почему в классе System такое можно, а в моём классе нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В классе System такое можно, потому что инициализация этих членов происходит с помощью [native](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/971720/235436)-методов. [Здесь](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/cf44386c8fe3/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#l246) можно увидеть их объявление:

```
private static native void setIn0(InputStream in);
private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
private static native void setErr0(PrintStream err);
```

С точки зрения языка Java значения final-переменных, действительно, нельзя изменить обычными средставми, поэтому у вас возникает ошибка. Но native-методы позволяют это сделать. В спецификации языка есть даже отдельный [пункт](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3) об изменении final-переменных.

Comment: я добавил в свой класс private static native void setOut0(PrintStream var0); - непомогло .

Comment: Так у вас нет исходного кода этого метода. И вы вряд ли его вызываете. Исходники здесь http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/native/java/lang/System.c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951620/7485582

Comment: тоесть out в System.out.println() это экземпляр класса PrintStream собранный классом System  под мою Джава машину ?

Comment: @Aleksspb33, native-методы платформозависимы в отличие от самого языка Java, что позволяет произвести оптимизации для конкретной машины.

Comment: вроде понял . спасибо !